# Passing static variable to function

Tags: c

I have a `ptr` variable that is updated in a function. I want to pass this variable to `function2`, which is in a different .c file. 
Is it legal to pass a static variable to a function not in the same .c file? Would it be safer to just keep a global `ptr` without `static` keyword?

```
static Event * ptr = NULL;

void function(Event * newPtr)
{

   ptr = newPtr;
   function2(ptr);
}

//in separate c file
void function2(Event * pointer)
{
    pointer->event = 2;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's legal. Whether or not it's "correct", depends on what that function may do to the data.

Comment: When you use a variable in a function call, you don't really pass the variable itself, only it's *value*. Or rather, a *copy* of its value.

Comment: Why `function2(ptr)` and not `function2(newPtr)` directly?

Comment: Try to avoid static variables altogether. Having said that, variables are not passed to functions in C, values are, specifically rvalues.

Comment: @n.m. That's not really helpful advise. There are plenty of cases where `static` is perfectly fine. For example it can be used for private encapsulation purposes on single-core, single-threaded systems. For example, it is very commonly used that way in embedded systems, and it is entirely good practice. As opposed to using globals/extern, which is 100% bad practice on pretty much every kind of system. `static` file scope variables should only be avoided if there are multiple threads or multiple instances of objects using the static. It all depends on context, you can't say "always avoid it".

Comment: @Lundin No, static variables are just as evil as globally visible external ones. There are cases when static variables are *necessary evil* but they are few and far between.

Comment: @n.m. I just gave you an example of when they are good practice. How would you then write a driver, for a hardware of which there only exists one instance, which contains an interrupt, where the driver functions need to communicate with the driver ISR internally? It sounds as if you are used to program very specific C applications and therefore assume that the kind of applications you do are how C should be done universally. It smells like Linux programming.

Comment: @Lundin The assumption of uniqueness of anything almost always turns out to be wrong, so just don't make it if you can heelp it.

Comment: @n.m. I work on a large code base for an embeded system in C and we have a lot of static variables, they are not evil at all, they are a programming tool like any other that serves its purpose.

Comment: @Fredrik "we have a lot of static variables" doesn't entail "static variables are OK". They are tools indeed but some tools are better left in the drawer most of the time.

Answer (score 3):

Static variable

```
static Event * ptr = NULL;
```

cannot be seen from other source file, but if you pass it as argument, it is just copied on stack same as other pointers, so you can do it that way.

But i would pass it as `const` pointer and *explicitly* document it that it is `static` variable for others.

```
void function2(Event * const pointer)
{
    pointer->event = 2;
}
```

Comment: Why `const` and explicity document it? There is no reason for that.

Answer (score 3):

`static` specifier only limits the scope of the variable (`internal linkage`).
But when you pass the `ptr`, the address contained in `ptr` will be used and that is completely legal (no problem in compilation, since you are not using the variable `ptr`, you are using the value contained in it).

But think twice before doing that since you declared as `static` if some other person looks at your code, its gives an impression that the variable is used only in this file. If the code in `function2` does anything to the passed pointer (assume you have dynamically allocated memory to your pointer and it is freed in `function2` and you tried to delete/access in your file where you declared `ptr`).

If you take care of what `function2` is about to do with the pointer, then its completely safe to do so. But as I mentioned above, it is not a good practice to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You can do whatever you want with it. Static means global storage && local file **symbo**l visibility. But variable can be used as you wish